# Razor .resx view localization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, localization, translation, resx

How to easily localize the view (only .cshtml and the javascript in this file). 
Please help me, I've spent about 5 hours with 0 result already, the official documentation is overcomplicated https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1
Everything easier is outdated.

I am stuck with creating a name for the resx file

The View is called `IndexPage.cshtml`, the resource file is called `SharedResource.en-US.resx`

Using this

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
<p>@Localizer["Hello"]</p>
```

prints me just Hello, but not the translation of this.

Comment: Could you share your Controller and your Startup.cs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it prints `Hello` is because it `cannot find` the matched localization resource file for `the class or view you want to localize`, when it cannot find the resource name/key it would print the text (key) as is.

There are two approaches to do localization:

#### A) If you decide to go with the way mentioned in the official documentation `(using Localizer/IStringLocalizer)` you need to do the following:

1. create a Resources folder and put in it the `.resx files` **with the proper naming convention which is**:

> You need to name your `.resx files` to mimic the path of their associated `view/class file` that you want to localize.
>
> E.g.: if you have a `HomeController` with `Index action`, and you have a view for that Index located under `Views/Home/Index.cshtml` you then need to name your `resx file` as:
>   views.home.index.en-US.resx
>
> or you can `create same folder structure` as the `views/controller` inside your resources folder, e.g.:
>   `Resources/Views/Home/Index.en.resx`.

2. In your `startup.cs` you need to register the required services to support localization and configure them by doing:

```cs
//in your ConfigureServices method

services.AddLocalization(opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });

services.AddMvc()
     .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
     .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
```

and:

```cs
//in your Configure method

var supportedCultures = new[]
{
//add the cultures you support..
     new CultureInfo("en-US"),
     new CultureInfo("fr"),
};

app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
     // Set the default culture.
     DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"), 
     // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
     SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
     // UI strings that we have localized.
     SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
});
```

3. When a request comes in it goes through a `specific middleware` to decide which culture to use `using one of these providers`:

   - `QueryStringRequestCultureProvider`.
   - `CookieRequestCultureProvider`. Most apps uses this mechanism to persist the user culture.
   - `AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider`.
4. Run your app and test it using `QueryStringRequestCultureProvider`, e.g.: `https://localhost:5001/?culture=fr`

> Note:
>   You need to have a `culture fallback behavior` which will handle any unsupported cultures by having a `.resx` file without `.Language_Code` prefix, e.g.: `views.home.index.resx` which basically contains the main language of your app.

---

#### B) If you feel like approach A is too much:

If you want to have specific number of `.resx` files only e.g.: `SharedResource.resx`, `SharedResource.fr.resx`, `Messages.resx`, `Messages.fr.resx`, and `Errors.resx` , `Errors.fr.resx`, then you can create those `.resx files` inside your `Resources folder`.

Then in your `startup.cs`:

```cs
//in your ConfigureServices method
services.AddLocalization(opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });
services.AddMvc();
```

and:

```cs
//in your Configure method

var supportedCultures = new[]
{
//add the cultures you support..
     new CultureInfo("en-US"),
     new CultureInfo("fr"),
};

app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
     // Set the default culture.
     DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"), 
     // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
     SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
     // UI strings that we have localized.
     SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
});
```

Finally, you can access the resource files using the resource file name, e.g.: @SharedResource.Hello

> Note: you need to reference Resources in your `_ViewImports.cshtml` to be able to use them in your views.

---

I know this is a long answer, but i wanted to provide you with 2 different approaches so you can decide which is best for your use-case.

Comment: `@SharedResource.Hello` would work just fine if you followed B, but you need to import your `Resources` folder `namespace` to your _ViewImports.cshtml, e.g.: `@using YOUR_APP.Resources`